# Field translation in function GROUP_BY in OPENERP 6.1

Tags: python, odoo

I have the following problem, when I do a group_by by date in a view, the months of the year are not translated. How can I show these values in the language I have selected?
regards

in the view:

```
<filter string="Date" icon="terp-go-year" name="Date" context="{'group_by':'create_date'}"/>
```

in the .py:

```
'create_date': fields.datetime('Date')
```

OUTPUT:

[translate group_by error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH8uo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in the language locale. I load a language and change sucessful